# Compare unequal lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to compare two unequal lists:

```
a = [6]
b = [6,7,8]
```

I want following:

```
if list a == list b:
   #do something for matching elements from both lists
else:
     #do something for non-matching elements
```

Any suggestions are appreciative.

Comment: Does your code run and you want suggestions? Try [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: I sincerely request for reason of negative vote else I won't be able to improve my questions in future.

Comment: What is the desired output? `[6, 7, 8]` or `[6]`?

Comment: Not downvoter, but it's unclear what you are asking. That's the reason why the question has 3 close votes with the reason: **unclear what you're asking**

Comment: if elements of list `a` matches elements of list `b` then `do something` else `do something else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the elements which exist in both lists, the following list comprehension should work:

```
c = [item for item in b if item in a]
```

Like so:

```
>>> a = [6]
>>> b = [6,7,8]
>>> c = [item for item in b if item in a]
>>> c
[6]
>>>
```

If you want to, say print something every time the values match, use the following `for` loop:

```
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        print '%d in both sets!' %(i)
    else:
        print '%d does not match!' %(i)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> a = [6, 7]
>>> b = [6, 7, 8]
>>> for i in b:
...     if i in a:
...             print '%d in both sets!' %(i)
...     else:
...             print '%d does not match!' %(i)
... 
6 in both sets!
7 in both sets!
8 does not match!
>>>
```

Comment: I already have matching element but instead I want to perform some calculations for elements which exist in both lists otherwise do some other calculations.

Comment: What kind of calculations?

Comment: In second part of your answer, I got 6 and 7 but `else` condition isn't working to get `8` as non-matching element.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [6]
b = [6,7,8]
```

if you want read element by element in a for loop, use this

```
for element in b :
   # what do you want to do; Example
    print element
```

Result : --> 678

Comment: `for element in b :`
it will take one by one each element into b and apply for loop
As B is a list, element will be firt element in the list for the first loop, 2nd element for the 2nd loop, ....

if b was a string, element will the 1st char for the 1st loop, ...