# Create function to compare unequal lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Piggybacking on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866378/compare-unequal-lists)

I want to create a function to compare two lists:

```
def test(a,b):
    c=[]
    for item in b:
        if item in a:
            return c[item]
```

The function above gives me an error: list index out of range, if i define and and b:
a=[2,3,5,8]
b=[4,5,6,9,8]

Why is this the case?

Comment: list must have the same long

Comment: example: `c[item]` is evaluated to `c[5]` and there's no such index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. `c[item]` will reference the "item" index of the `c` list. It will NOT add the value of "item" to the list as you are intending. For example: 5 is the first common value in both lists. `c[5]` references the 6th element in the `c` array which does not exist; hence your error.
2. You are using `return` which ends the function call and is going to simply pass the value of `c[5]` to the caller of the function.

Try the following:

```
def test(a,b):
    c=[]
    for item in b:
        if item in a:
            c.append(item)
    return c
```

`.append(item)` will add the value of `item` as a new element at the end of the list referenced.

Once the loop has finished, the function will now return the whole `c` list as you intended.

Using your example lists of `a = [2, 3, 5, 8]` and `b = [4, 5, 6, 9, 8]`, calling `test(a, b)` return `[5, 8]` correctly.

Comment: Makes sense now.  Thanks for breaking this down.

Comment: Is there a way to include a unique statement in the for statement that won't duplicate numbers in c?

Comment: Try altering the if statement to:
`if (item in a) and (item not in c):`

Comment: I tried using set(b) and that worked, but appreciate also knowing about the if and approach.  thanks Nathan!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access items in c that do not exist.
Try running this and see what your output is:

```
a=[2,3,5,8]
b=[4,5,6,9,8]
c=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
for item in b:
    if item in a:
        print(c[item])
```

You get item 5 and 8 - 'f' and 'i' from c.
This works great if those elements exist, but not so much if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

For your algorithm, your lists will need to be the same length. But you can definitely improve it to compare variable length lists.